# Does dark matter originate from matter falling into a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, dark-matter

Is it possible that due to the fact that dark matter is clumped around black holes, that the dark matter used to be matter, fell into a black hole, and simply became dark?

Furthermore, if the total "dark mass" of a galaxy is changing over time, maybe this is related to the amount of mass being consumed by the black hole(s) within it.

These are just some thoughts from the coffee table, harsh criticism welcomed.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Exchange! Note that this is not a place to discuss personal theories (you should try physics fora for this), so I'll vote to close. However, I can tell you that this theory is not good, because we can measure the mass of black holes, but it still doesn't add up.

Comment: Note also that the non-personal-theory question you could ask already has an answer here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26780/why-cant-dark-matter-be-black-holes?rq=1

Comment: nice idea but the center black holes masses are known and they don't fit the missing matter equations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wouldn't work because the dark matter wouldn't be able to escape the black hole. Also, the measured mass of black holes contradicts this.

Comment: Hi. Isn't also a fact that in some theories dark matter is is not necessary? See Inhomogeneous cosmology.